# How to transfer data from RDBMS to elasticsearch DB during data load in RDBMS and then work with Elastic search DB ? It is a springboot project

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, rdbms

I need to pull data from RDBMS like oracle to ELastic search DB. I will be working in a springboot application and also have a requirement that whenever RDBMS data gets refreshed the Elastic DB should also get refreshed i.e both in sync. SO finally instead to querying from RDBMS each time I would get data from ELasticDB? How can I do this considering latest version of elastic search and springBoot app?

Comment: Please share what you have done/tried so far?

Comment: I am new to elastic search and as of now I have just created some a dummy project using springboot and in build elastic data search dependency. I am using restHighLevelClient to cretae Elastic data.

Comment: Something like this:
Map<K,V> dataMap = objectMapper.convertValue(book, Map.class);
 IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(INDEX, TYPE, book.getId()).source(dataMap);
 IndexResponse response = restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest);

But how can I map RDBMS data to elastic search DB. Do I need to individually create all the indexes, types and documents or is there a way to directly create Elastic data from RDBMS? how can I populate elastic data in most efficient way from some RDBMS in a springboot applications that should load data in all environments like dev, prod, qa ?